# What to do with questions where the accepted answer doesn't answer the general question (while solving the narrow problem)

Tags: discussion

*I urge you to not consider this as post of indignation or something. I simply expound my observations. I have no intention to run in circles, waving hands, attempt to open everyone's eyes and appeal for revolution. It's personal opinion and thoughts, that visit me pretty consistently for quite prolonged period already.*

I was wondering about SO opinion on answers that are solving the poster's problem, but not answering the actual question.
As [may be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494070/accessing-a-class-property-without-using-dot-operator)
if it is needed, I may search more. that's why I'm writing: I see those topics more and more often (but, to be fair, their dates spread kinda evenly on time scale).

Yes, it is up to user, whether accept answer or not. but that what I'm thinking: even topic with half-answered question is better, even `non-constructive/off-topic` question is "better" (those one, that curiously have many good answers and useful information. what's more curious, they are not rare at all). even duplicates are better, since they can be answered and the new answer may be more detailed or clear, than the old.

Those practices may be considered bad by some. meanwhile I'm talking about the subject of this post: it's much more harmful and unhealthy for SO. man in doubt opens "recommend the software plz!" topic and finds valuable info, man in doubt opens the like of question under discussion, reads the accepted answer and.. what? finds unrelated answer, rereads title, rereads question.. et voi la: ["is SO over the hill?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305547/is-stack-overflow-losing-its-popularity-and-quality). I'm personally not concur with that post, to say the least.

occasionally, pages of this kinds contain the good/right answer below. but this cannot be considered "fix". it is half-measure. also, i suppose, post having accepted answer will attract less users, who may contribute. not because they feel hurt they will not get reputation, but there is a green checkmark already, question is answered. at the same time, users that are seeking answer may be deceived and take the wrong path.

I know, answered questions get some love sometimes too, now imagine "flawed" accepted answer is marked.

Maybe I'm overdramatizing; yes, "eggs can't teach the hen", and so on. anyway I'm ready to adjust my perspective.

Actually, just wanted to ask, is "accepted" status permanent, or it may be tweaked by moderators? or may be moderators can mark those nasty answers, as they mark duplicates, off-topic, etc., and it's OK for user to flag the answer he considers unsatisfactory, expecting it will be revised?

Marks alone would be enough. kinda "FYI: accepted answer solves particular case, while not resolving the general problem raised", "may be deprecated", "accepted solution is not optimal, refer to other answers", "objective c is an utter lackluster, consider never using it again"

It's beyond my comprehension: some topics are closed with reason like (pardon my memory) "question is too specific and will become obsolete soon, doesn't possess any valuable knowledge potential etc." But answers? When they even fail to answer the question from topic Title field, when they are addressing the narrowest ad hoc solution of single particular problem. When do they become obsolete? Instantly? (btw, not even once, those "will become obsolete soon"-closed topics had helped me, while being closed for 5+ years to date). That's very cool they are just closed, not deleted.

And of course, no offence towards those, whos answers I indirectly mentioned as half-acceptable. They helped someone anyway, and surely contributed more to community, than I, myself. SO community is the greatest, I owe it much, and it certainly has almost unmatched amount of my respect.

Comment: the accepted status is the prerogative of the OP, NO ONE ELSE. it doesn't mean much, except "the OP found this to be the best". I tend to count the mark as just another upvote when I look up stuff. If you see a bad accepted answer... comment, downvote

Comment: This is an awful lot of rambling words just to ask if the accepted answer can be changed. I suspect there's a broader question you want to ask, but I can't tell what it is. It seems to be buried under side remarks. Can you edit to focus a little better?

Comment: It is very, very common that a question posits a rather nonsensical premise.  The OP just throwing spaghetti at the wall, hoping that some of it will stick and helps an SO user to come up with the proper solution.  Very much what happened in the question you linked.  It would never have been asked if the OP knew about implicit conversion operators.  The answer is correct, the question is ho-hum.

Comment: blinkenlight is well known to answer that kind of poor questions.

Comment: So in response to being told that your question was 90% fluff, and that you spent *way* too much text just to ask a two sentence question, you've decided to just add in an additional paragraph of complete fluff instead?  If your goal is to prevent as many people as possible from bothering to read the question and figure out what you're actually asking, you seem to be generally succeeding.

Comment: @TylerH irrelevant to this stuff: i suppose you are using some script to capitalize first letters in sentences and `I` pronoun? please, share your wisdom. for some reason people get irritated, when i use capitals only in places it makes actual sense. i'm not saying either is good or bad, but i guess i have to play by others rules. but i can't get myself used to capitalization. so making it automatic would be great. also, i wonder, why no one tells others (or me) they use english, let's say, frivolously. i'm sure i have much cruder errors tolerated, but write `i` and everyone loses their minds!

Comment: @HansPassant no questions would never have been asked, if the OPs knew about how to answer them. (tho, in this case i'm not agree answer answers the question, as i said before)

Comment: @zloidooraque No, I edited the post manually.

Comment: @TylerH not that I'm unthankful, but not worth, as you see ((= m.b. it's some sport? Anyway, [here you go](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/capitalize-sentences.php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderators can only remove acceptance from an answer by deleting it; they cannot remove the acceptance while leaving the answer there.

If the OP wants to accept an answer, they can.  Even if you don't like it.  If you feel that the answer isn't a helpful answer to the question asked, then you can downvote it, and if you want, you're welcome to add a comment explaining why it's not helpful.  If you want to add another answer that you feel would be more helpful, you're welcome to do so.

Comment: With **first paragraph** you've answered the question, that induced me to write this set of letters. It quickly became a flow of thoughts that erupted so chaotically out of my 4-days-no-sleep brain. As of **second paragraph**: I've addressed all those options, except downvoting in text (and it would be insanely stupid to reproach smb they didn't parse/interpret it or forgot something =))). And the fact, that i don't like answer doesn't instantiate any emotions, btw.

Comment: Strangely enough, the meaning can be extracted out of this whole outrage: I just shared my opinion, that ability to flag accepted answer with "Needs revision" by users and mark with "Treat with care" by moderators could become a nice feature. It may stimulate users to make topic more valuable, and explicitly notice others to raise awareness. that's not much, but at least now i know, what happens when you switch off the _concentration_ you were in 100 hours straight. and what a beautiful architecture we have now. heh, sorry, seems like idle talkativeness is a payback. gotta catch someone IRL